Should page navigation in AEM handled through javascript or anchor tag?
I have 4 button on homepage and upon clicking it I want to get navigated on another page.
I tried first something like this.
<a href="/content/travel/us/en/addticket.html" class="button-link">
<button class="add-ticket">
<span> ADD LEADS </span>
</button>
</a>

But it was not working.
Then I tried to do it using javascript and redirection was working.
Html
<button class="add-ticket">
<span> ADD LEADS </span>
</button>

Js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
const addticketbutton =document.getElementById('add-ticket');
if(addticketbutton){
    addticketbutton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.location.href="/content/travel/us/en/addticket.html";
    });
});

What problem I'm facing with javascript is often i need to reload page or refresh. Sometimes redirection works sometimes not. Also achor tag gives us option to open in new tab.
I'm beginer in AEM and don't know how to do this.

It's navigation, not redirection.  Have you tried a simple link to make sure that works?

Yes simple link works. Like "https://www.quora.com/"

I don't know how aem works and whether or not you can safely use domContentLoaded event.  I would try just putting the addEventListener code in a script tag right after the button, and not wrapping it in domContentLoaded.

I tried first something like this...But it was not working. What happened when you tried it? I'm not familiar with aem, but it seems that navigating via javascript here is overly complicated.

I just want to confirm that for your basic HTML implementation that you included a <base> tag so that the HTML knows the base path for all other relative paths ?
*Since you mentioned a simple link like quora was working.

I am not familiar with AEM, but maybe you could change the code.
HTML - You do not need to wrap the text in a span, unless you want to change the color of certain text in it.
<a href="/content/travel/us/en/addticket.html" class="button-link">
<button class="add-ticket">ADD LEADS</button>
</a>

Also, do you really need the button?
<a href="/content/travel/us/en/addticket.html" class="button-link add-ticket">ADD LEADS</a>

Also some docs from Adobe about embedding links in AEM.

Thanks for accepting and the bounty, but can you please comment what solved your problem? Other people may have the same problem and it would be helpful to them.
